# Identify a spring-batch job instance with incrementer

Tags: spring, spring-batch

let me discribe shortly what I want and what I - maybe - know.

- I want spring-batch to run a async job; in future more jobs.
- The job gets two parameters: an external id and a year.
- The job should be able to be restarted after completion because the user wants to run a job with the same parameters again and again.
- Only one job should be executed with the same parameters at the same time.
- From outside (web interface) it should be possible to query if a job is running by job name and parameters.
- The querier could be different from the job starter so an instance or execution id is not present.

I know that a job instance is the representation of the job(name) and the parameters and - like you commented - I cannot rerun a job with the same parameters if the instance/execution is marked completed - except I use a incrementer.

But this changes the parameters by adding a run.id. Now a job is restartable but I and sping-batch itself are not able to identify a running job instance  (by name and *original* parameters) anymore because every job run results in a new instance.

And the question "why would one would restart a successfully completed job instance?" is easy to answer: The user outside don't know about job/instance/execution. The user will start some data processing for a year again and again. And it's my task to make it possible :).

So it would be nice if spring-batch can let the user know "the job with your *original* parameters is still running".

Question:
What would be a good solution for my needs?

I didn't tried something but thought about it. Maybe I can write an own JobDao for my query? But this will not solve the run-instance-at-same-time problem. Or I can customize the JdbcJobInstanceDao or SimpleJobRepository? Maybe I must add a own job_key which contains only the original parameters?

Comment: I found a solution for my use-case and write it in the answer section. It's not exactly the answer of my question but for now it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly understand the answer I am going to give to your question, it is important to know the difference and understand the relation between a job, a job instance and a job execution in Spring Batch. The [The Domain Language of Batch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/domain.html#domainLanguageOfBatch) section of the reference documentation explains that in details with examples.

> The job should be able to be restarted after completion.

This is not possible by design, or more precisely, a job *instance* cannot be restarted after completion by design (Think of it like "why would one would restart a successfully completed job *instance*?").

> From outside (web interface) it should be possible to query if an instance is running by job name and parameters. There querier could be different from the job starter so an instance or execution id is not present.

The `JobExplorer` is the API you are looking for. You can ask for job instances and job executions as needed.

> Question: What would be a good solution for my needs?

In your case, you receive an external ID and a year as a job execution request. Those two parameters can be used as identifying parameters to define job instances. With this in place, if a job instance is failed, you can restart it by using the same parameters.

I see no need for an incrementer in your case. The incrementer is useful for jobs for which the instances can be defined as a "sequence" that can be "incremented". I see no need to create a custom `DAO` or `JobRepository` neither, you should be able to implement your requirement with the built-in components by correctly defining what a job *instance* is.

Answer (score 0):

For my use-case I have to check if a execution for a job/parameters-combination is running. The parameters here are without run.id of an incrementor. This check must be done before a job run and by explicit rest call. Normally spring-batch checks for running  executions but because of the used incrementor every job instance is unique and it will never find any.

So I created a bean with a check method and made use of `jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);`. The result can then compared with the used paramters by iterating over `JobExecution.getJobParameters().getParameters()`.

The bean can be used in the rest-method and in an own implemention of `JobLauncher.run()`.

Another solution would be to store the increment separately for a job/parameters-combination. But I don't want to do this not least because I think a framework like spring-batch should do this for me or supports me by reusing/restarting a completed job instance.